Blocks' title and body in the same slide under default beamer theme with allowframebreaks option
I am preparing a presentation with the default beamer theme, since I need something really simple.
I am using a background image that has to fade from right to left, and I modified the margins in order to have the rightmost part of the image completely visible. The default theme allows the blocks to be completely transparent.
I need to use allowframebreaks option1: but as soon as I have several blocks spanning multiple slides, the title and the body of some blocks are in different slides.
How I can fix that? I tried several options, such as using one of the fancy themes and implementing the solution depicted in this answer, but it requires a lot of work to modify all the other options for titlepage, general layout et cetera.
Down below a MWE.
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings} 
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=40mm} 

\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[opacity=1, at=(current page.center),inner sep=0pt,scope fading=west,blend mode=screen] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image.pdf}};
}

\title{Test}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

        \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
            \frametitle{Go on}
    
            \begin{block}{Block 1}
                \lipsum[1]
            \end{block}
            
            \begin{block}{Block 2}
                \lipsum[1]
            \end{block}
    
        \end{frame}
\end{document} 


1 I know that allowframebreaks is a really dangerous option, but since it is a presentation for a game night with friends and not for conferences or job stuff, using it makes me avoid to do an extensive "layout checking" and inserting in a lot of suitable places \begin{frame} ... \end{frame}.

Quick hack: you could use the tcolorbox inner theme which replaces normal beamer blocks with tcolorboxes:
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings} 
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=40mm} 

\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[opacity=1, at=(current page.center),inner sep=0pt,scope fading=west,blend mode=screen] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image.pdf}};
}

\title{Test}
\date{}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}
\tcbsetforeverylayer{
  enhanced,
  interior hidden,
  title hidden
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

        \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
            \frametitle{Go on}
    
            \begin{block}{Block 1}
                \lipsum[1]
            \end{block}
            
            \begin{block}{Block 2}
                \lipsum[1]
            \end{block}
    
        \end{frame}
\end{document} 



Great! I turn off the update of my TeXLive and I had to manually add to the directory the .sty!

This problem has been fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/8af7e4e6682f2aee9141756b5f7aafe7a5cbab96 , which should be included in beamer v3.72 or newer.

